# What would happen if a true vacuum expanded within the event horizon of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, vacuum, event-horizon, qft-in-curved-spacetime, bubbles

If a bubble of a false vacuum decaying to a true vacuum state (in one of the fields described by the Standard Model) somehow expanded starting from a point within the event horizon of a black hole, what would be the result?

This question was previously asked, but not answered, here: [If vacuum decay was somehow triggered inside a black hole, would the rest of the universe notice?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/677046/)

Comment: The inside and outside regions of a black hole are separated by time, not by space. The inside is in the future relative to outside. Nothing happening in the future can affect us today.